# In AngularJS, share data between controllers and add callback behavior for authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an Angular front-end, trying to not overcomplicate things by using breeze or restangular but still code properly.
The problem is that my code seems to get bloated more than anything else after writing just a few lines.

The point is to save the user in a cookie and return it at the same time when someone logs in.

The Auth service

```
var userResource = $resource('/users/:id');
    var currentUser = $cookieStore.get("user") || {};
    return {
        currentUser: currentUser,
        login: function(userId, type, callback) {
            var thiz = this;
            return userResource.save({id: userId}, {}, function(promise) {
                promise.then(function(result) {
                    thiz.currentUser = result.data;
                    $cookieStore.put("user", thiz.currentUser);
                    if(callback) {
                        callback(thiz.currentUser);
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        users: function() {
            return userResource.query();
        }
    };
```

The AuthCtrl controller

```
    $scope.login = function(userId, type) {
        Auth.login(userId, type, function(result) {
            $scope.user = result;
        });
    };
    Auth.login("someuser", 'basic', function(result) {
        $scope.user = result;
    });
    $scope.users = Auth.users();
```

In another controller :

```
    $scope.user = Auth.currentUser;    
    Snippets.query({user: $scope.user.id}, function(snippets) {
        $scope.snippets = snippets;
    });
```

The reason I am resolving the promise in the service is because I want to save the currentUser and put it in the cookieStore (which might not be available on mobiles but whatever).

The problem is that by doing this I am not returning the promise but the resource, which forces me to pass a callback in all of my login calls.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the resource in a promise, and return the promise. This should work:

```
var userResource = $resource('/users/:id');
    var currentUser = $cookieStore.get("user") || {};
    return {
        currentUser: currentUser,
        login: function(userId, type, $q) {
            var self = this;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            // return currentUser if it is present.
            if (this.currentUser.id) {
              return $q.when(this.currentUser);
            }
            userResource.save({id: userId}, {}, function(response) {
              if (!response.error) {
                self.currentUser = response.data;
                $cookieStore.put("user", self.currentUser);
                deferred.resolve(self.currentUser);
              } else {
                deferred.reject(response.error);
              }
            });
          return deferred.promise;
        },
        users: function() {
            return userResource.query();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I had tried this way, the problem is that the currentUser is then empty when the SnippetCtrl is reached

Comment: Is SnippetCtrl a partial? If yes, then perhaps you need to resolve login before your SnippetCtrl is reached?

Comment: Yes it is a partial, I want everything to be dynamic which is why I wanted to defer the currentUser resolution in the first place.So that templates get rendered and filled as data comes in

Comment: In that case, in SnippetCtrl, you could do it like,
Auth.login('someUser', 'basic').then(function(user) {
  Snippets.query({user: user.id}, function(snippets) {
    $scope.snippets = snippets;
  });
});
...

Comment: Yeah the point is to avoid having to write login in every controller though. What I want is for the SnippetCtrl to defer its queries until the user's promise has been resolved.